# WPF returning NULL on some WCF methods

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

I am upgrading a current WinForms application to a WPF application and am coming across a weird issue.

Firstly, the method (*GetLectures*) is working on the current application so I know that there is nothing wrong with the WCF method.

So In my WPF application 'V*iewModel*' class I am calling the method to get all the Lectures (*GetLectures*).

```
public List<Publish.Lecture> Lecture
{
     get
     {
         return Client.GetLectures(Session).ToList();
     }
}
```

which then I am binging to my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid BorderBrush="#e5e5e5" CellStyle="{StaticResource episodeDataGridCell}" RowHeaderWidth="0" GridLinesVisibility="None" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,24,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Lecture}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="435" Width="472" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" CanUserResize="False" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Episode" Width="150"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" CanUserResize="False" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Access" Width="150"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" CanUserResize="False" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Player" Width="150"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I am getting an error in the '*ViewModel*' which says:

```
Value cannot be null.
```

Which is stating that nothing is being returned?

I have tried calling another method in that WCF service '*GetChannel*' and this works fine.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: that seems like a bad idea to bind a property to a service like that. it will call the service everytime the property is used.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks for letting me know, I will look into this.

Answer (score 1):

In case your method GetLectures doesn't return anything.. You have no check. Instead of proceeding directly to `.ToList()`, try checking the returned value for null or may be use Linq to check `.Any()`

```
var ABC = Client.GetLectures(Session);

If(ABC != null && ABC.Any())
   return ABC.ToList();
```

Comment: Although you should not write a service call in the get... Every binding and every time this property is accessed, the code will force a service call..

Comment: please use the code formatting tool to format the code via editing. It makes your answer stand out as cleaner and more readable.